# Need helping adding camera controls to Vulkan cube spinning demo

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I am working with Vulkan's demo files, specifically vkcube.cpp and editing it to add camera zoom controls on button press, just zoom in and out. However, it is really not what I am used to since I am used to OpenGL so not exactly sure how to go about this. And none of it is my code so I'm fairly confused.

```
 mat4x4_perspective(demo->projection_matrix, (float)degreesToRadians(45.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    mat4x4_look_at(demo->view_matrix, eye, origin, up);
    mat4x4_identity(demo->model_matrix);


    demo->projection_matrix[1][1] *= -1;  // Flip projection matrix from GL to Vulkan orientation.
```

this is mostly what I've been looking at, I know the forward vector will be the third column of the inverted view matrix, but not sure how to use that information in order to make the camera actually move.

I tried to get the forward vector from the view matrix by just making a new one and grabbing [0][2] [1][2] and [2][2], but I wasn't able to modify it in any way. Then I tried to update the view matrix with new numbers but couldn't modify that either.